# How can I search questions where I've commented?

Tags: support

Yesterday I found a question I though I could answer, but needed a bit more info from the OP so I added a comment.

Later at home, I remembered the question and wanted to read it all over again, but I couldn't find the question.

**Is there a way to search the places where I've commented?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you want [the 'activity' tab in your profile](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/14831/roflo?tab=activity)

It look like this is the question you are after: [How to design this kind of relations in a database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/27827/1396)